# query CartoDB private tables with the api-key show error 503

Tags: carto

I'm doing a test map with two tables, one with polygons and the other with points. I create a layer with two sublayers (polygons and points).

The user selects a state and the query is updated showing the selected state and the points contained therein.

I have a code that works with public tables, but when I try to use the api-key (as seem on [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84703/how-to-use-cartodb-js-with-api-key-for-privacy-of-data)) I get an **Error 503 backend read error** when the query updates

This is my code for createLayer:

```
   cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name:user,
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers:[subLayer0Options, subLayer1Options],
    options: {
      table_name: point_table,
      user_name: user,
      extra_params: {
        map_key: key
      }
    }
  })
  .done(function(layer) {
    layer.options.extra_params.map_key = key;
    layer.addTo(map);
    layer.setInteraction(true);
    updateMap(layer);
  })
```

The updateMap() function:

```
 function updateMap(layer){
    layer.setInteraction(true)

    // change the query for the sublayer(0) == polygons
    var myquery0= "SELECT b.* FROM usa_states b, point_table s WHERE b.state = '"+state+"' AND st_intersects(b.the_geom_webmercator, s.the_geom_webmercator)"
    var subLayer0Options = {
      sql: myquery0,
      cartocss: "#usa_states {polygon-fill: #0f3b82;}"
    }
    var states = layer.getSubLayer(0)
    states.set(subLayer0Options);
    //states.setInteraction(false);      

    // change query of the sublayer(1) == points
    var myquery1= "SELECT s.* FROM usa_states b, points_table s WHERE b.state = '"+state +"' AND st_intersects(b.the_geom_webmercator, s.the_geom_webmercator)"

    var subLayer1Options = {
      sql: myquery1,
      cartocss: "#point_table{marker-fill: #FFCC00;}",
      interactivity: 'cartodb_id, column1, column2, column3',
      infowindow: true 
    }
    var points = layer.getSubLayer(1)
    points.set(subLayer1Options);
    points.setInteraction(true)
    points.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
    //cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, points, ['cartodb_id, column1, column2, column3'])

    var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: user, api_key: key});
    sql.getBounds(myquery1).done(function(bounds) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds)
    });
  })
};
```

Use the apikey on the client is only for local testing, I read [something](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87869/cartodb-sql-query-of-public-visualization-of-a-private-table) about how the maps with private tables now **must** use "[template maps](https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft-cartodb/blob/master/docs/Template-maps.md)".

Edit:

I'm trying to do a template.json file but I don't know how to put two sublayers in the layergroup:

```
"layergroup": {
   // see https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft/wiki/MapConfig-specification
   "version": "1.0.1",
   // Array of layers defined in render order
   "layers": [{ 
     "type": "cartodb",
     "options": {
       "cartocss_version": "2.1.1", 
       "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: <%= color %>; }",
       "sql": "SELECT s.* FROM usa_states b, points_table s WHERE b.state = <%= state %> AND st_intersects(b.the_geom_webmercator, s.the_geom_webmercator)",
       "affected_tables": [ "usa_states", "points_table" ],
       "interactivity": [ "cartodb_id", "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"]
     }
   }]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never ever use api_key in frontend code.

In order to add more than one layer you can do this:

```
"layergroup": {
   // see https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft/wiki/MapConfig-specification
   "version": "1.0.1",
   // Array of layers defined in render order
   "layers": [{ 
     "type": "cartodb",
     "options": {
       "cartocss_version": "2.1.1", 
       "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: <%= color %>; }",
       "sql": "SELECT s.* FROM usa_states b, points_table s WHERE b.state = <%= state %> AND st_intersects(b.the_geom_webmercator, s.the_geom_webmercator)",
       "interactivity": [ "cartodb_id", "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"]
     }
   },{ 
     "type": "cartodb",
     "options": {
       "cartocss_version": "2.1.1", 
       "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: red; }",
       "sql": "SELECT * form table 2",
       "interactivity": [ "cartodb_id"]
     }
   }
  ]
 }
```

You don't need to specify affected_tables, backend does it for you